# Drawing maps in WPF

Tags: wpf, maps, countries

I want to draw a map in WPF without using any third party controls.

I need each and every state of all the countries, and based on certain conditions I want to color them.

How can I get the polygon shapes of each state of all the countries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is an SVG file with all the states](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/CPVI_US_states.svg) as separate polygons (look at the source!)

You can [convert it to xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764/xaml-to-svg) if you want and fill the state differently.

**EDIT**

Just [google for svg world map](http://www.google.com/search?q=worldmap%20svg). One of the first hits seems to be [a nice resource](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-vector-world-maps-collection/).

Comment: Thanks , but can I get the svg file for world map.